# ActionBar in Fragments with back button and logo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I've got `Activity` with `FirstFragment` which opens another `SecondFragment`.

I want to have this in my `FirstFragment`

[image: FirstFragment]

And I want to have this in my `SecondFragment`

[image: SecondFragment]

but now I've got this in both of them...

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Activity` :

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher); //for example
```

In your `FirstFragment` :

```
 ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

In your `SecondFragment`:

```
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: But I get different arrow style, my logo with app name has a margin (40dp maybe) on the left side and this is not clickable :/